# The performance of Azure PostgreSql is bad

Tags: postgresql, azure

I am using Azure PostgreSQL, in my web project, I save files(such as images,.csv) in table as bytea data type.

Now I can get files from Azure PostgreSQL successfully, but the performance is not so good. it will take more than `20s` to retrieve files if I request for multiple files, even sometimes I got `timeout error` from my web server. So is there anyone could give me some advice to solve this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: generally saving files in database is not a good idea , that can be actually the issue specially if you are on cloud

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  Taking 20 seconds to retrieve an unknown number of files of unknown size using a database of unknown spec may indicate a problem, or may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eshirvana said, saving files in databases is not a good idea. As we know,the performance that querying blobs or files in SQL is awful and it also greatly cost DB server memory. Saving URLs in DB only is recommended.

If you are using Azure Cloud, you can save your files in [Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-overview). And you can save your file storage blob URL in your DB table.

Your client could get the file URL from the webserver by SQL query and access files in Azure storage by the file URL. This way could ease the IO and memory pressure of your web server and greatly improve the query performance.

What's more, creating your SQL service in the region that you are in or near could also reduce network latency. You can see [all the Azure datacenter regions here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/).

Comment: Thanks so much Stanley Gong and eshirvana, the recommendation is right and it improved my SQL query performance like a charm! I tried to compare the time consumption that querying file data and file url, and query file url is much faaaaaster!! Thanks for all of your help!